# Injecting service in angular directive unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I'm trying to first fix the basic unit test that cli wrote for me. I'm new to unit testing so here's the code

```
import { MyDirective } from './my.directive';

describe('MyDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new MyDirective(); // it throws error here
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I need to inject ElementRef inside MyDirective

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing), which answers this case.

Answer (score 7):

I wasted a couple of hours during my problem-solving. Here is the answer. For example, if we need to inject `ElementRef` and `NgControl`:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { MyDirective } from './my.directive';

describe('MyDirective', () => {
    it('should create an instance', inject([ElementRef, NgControl], (elementRef: ElementRef, ngControl: NgControl) => {
        const directive = new MyDirective(elementRef, ngControl);
        expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to add what I've taken from the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-attribute-directives#testing-attribute-directives). I.e. that part that was helpful in my situation.

In short: Include a TestComponent in your spec and use `import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser'` to query the elements relevant for your tests.

```js
@Component({
  template: ` <p highlight="searchStr">Do highlight my searchStr, will ya!</p>`,
})
class TestComponent {}


describe('HighlightDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  let des: DebugElement[];

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HighlightDirective, TestComponent],
    }).createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // all elements with an attached HighlightDirective
    des = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(HighlightDirective));
  });

  it('should have highlighted debug elements', () => {
    expect(des.length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should mark search string', () => {
    for (const de of des) {
      console.log(de.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      expect(de.nativeElement.innerHTML).toContain(`<mark class="highlight">searchStr</mark>`);
    }
  });

});
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.